# Firebase + Socket.io. It does make sense?

Tags: javascript, firebase, socket.io

I am trying to create a multiplayer video game in real time that and in addition, I want to save the data of the games in the database.

I want to use socket.io for the multiplayer part and Firebase for the database. But I have read that it is redundant to use these technologies. Why?

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Realtime Database already uses a websocket to send and receive database updates in real time.  Adding another socket almost certainly wouldn't add much value, but cost a lost of engineering effort.

Similarly, Firestore uses grpc to do the same sort of thing.

It's up to you to determine if you can add more value to your game by using a custom websocket, beyond what's already provided by the service.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My main question is: with Firebase do I have to store each player's movement in the database (for example, he move a card to the left, and I want the other player to see how he moves it) in order to show it to the other player?

Comment: Yes, you would have to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The mere difference are the database technologies one can connect. eg. when having demand for a MySQL server, as Firebase is NoSQL. I've migrated the [socket.io](https://github.com/syslogic/androidx-socket.io) client to AndroidX, including the server. You'd need that server and would have to setup a channel per game, develop a net-code and add a database connection.